# Loop through cells in a range and lock cells based on their value

Tags: vba, excel

OK say i have a range of cells from A1:B10. The cells in the range A1 to A10 contain a dropdown list with 2 options (lock, dont_lock). The cells in the range B1 to B10 are empty cells which allow the user to enter data. what i want to do is lock individual cells based on values in the adjacent cell. so if cell A1 is set to "lock" then i lock cell B1. IF cell A2 is set to "dont_lock" then B2 is not locked and so on. I have tried using a for loop shown in my code below but it does not work. Can Anyone help ?

```
Dim rCell As Range
Dim rRng As Range

Set rRng = Sheet1.Range("A1:B10")

For Each rCell In rRng.Cells
    If rCell = "Lock" Then
    Range("B1").Locked = True

End If

Next rCell
```

Comment: can you attach a screen print of your sheet? :) You are very close to what you want to achieve anyway. When you say `Column A has drop down` menu, do you mean a [drop down list in Excel cell](http://www.contextures.com/xlDataVal01.html)?

Comment: It's fine you do not have to attach any images. Please look at my comments in the answer :)

Comment: Yes i mean drop down list option

Answer (score 4):

In Excel, cells are locked by default. If you want cells to be unlocked you have to actually specify that behavior. However, it doesn't matter if the cell is locked or not if the worksheet isn't currently protected. So if you want the locked behavior, make sure to call `Sheet1.Protect`.

Now if I understand your explanation correctly you would do better with something like this:

```
Dim rCell As Range
Dim rRng As Range

Set rRng = Sheet1.Range("A1:A10") 'Exclude B as you are only checking A.
Sheet1.Unprotect
For Each rCell In rRng.Cells
    'Avoid if else structure since locking depends on result of evaluation only.
    rcell.Offset(0,1).locked = rcell.Value = "Lock"
Next rCell
Sheet1.Protect
```

Comment: I tried your code it looks good but i get an error "unable to set the locked property of the range class"

Comment: The Sheet must be unprotected to changed the Locked property. I added in a `Sheet1.Unprotect` statement, that should resolve the issue.

Comment: @derek logically, I would choose this answer as the 'tickable' one ;) 1. He talks about important point here, for protecting, unprotecting the Sheet 2. Code is nice without IF/Else : very logical

Answer (score 1):

Try the following code. Only issue with your code is that rCell.value = "Lock" is missing. You are only locking Cell B1 for all cells, you are not locking the adjacent all cells :)

### ** THIS IS A SAMPLE CODE**

```
Option Explicit

Sub lockNextCell()
Dim wkSheet As Worksheet
Dim rng As Range, rCell As Range

Set wkSheet = Sheets("Sheets1") '-- use your own sheet
Set rng = wkSheet.Range("A3:A12") '-- use your own range

For Each rCell In rng
    If rCell.Offset(0, 0).Value = "Lock" Then
        rCell.Offset(0, 1).Locked = True '-- here we are locking the adjacent cell
    else
        rCell.Offset(0, 1).Locked = False
    End If
Next rCell

End Sub
```

Just a note as Daniel talks about protecting sheet:

Here is a [reference from MSDN](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/214081) :
"If you lock a cell and protect the worksheet, then you cannot type data into the cell, modify the data currently in the cell, or change other attributes of the cell (such as cell formatting)"

Comment: You're checking `A3:A12` but the OP indicated `A1:A10` as being the range that needs evaluated. Additionally, the code you added to define a worksheet object will almost definitely result in an error for the OP. Your code requires that they have a worksheet named "Sheets1". Their code requires that the Excel Object `Sheet1` wasn't deleted. Possibly you are not realizing that it is perfectly legal to call the sheet directly by it's Microsoft Excel Object name, thereby not requiring it to be found within the Sheets Collection. I'm not saying that's what the OP intended, just that it's valid code

Comment: @Daniel I mentioned in my comment to OP, that he is very close to the answer himself. I didn't mentioned this is *the exact code to use*. It's a sample for him to try. Infact I was admiring the fact you pointed out on protect Sheet. So each time you need to unproect protect your sheet.

Comment: That's fine. Sorry if I seemed overly harsh, I was just pointing out potential areas of improvement for your sample code. And decided to explain myself rather than just saying "I don't like it". +1

Comment: @DanielCook that's perfectly fine, thank you. Really I was learning something from you :) I usually do this explicit references to the sheets and range objects - always write my code in a Module ;) perhaps that's why it looks rather totally different from OP's should use. The other thing all codes I post here are mostly written on the spot, so my ranges are usually not what OP would use.